# Java Thread HashMap not persisting in Socket Connection

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, hashmap

Looks like am missing some concept, but unable to figure it out.
I am writing a socket program for multithreaded server in Java.
As a connection is accepted in my code by server socket, I would create a separate thread for handling all the client request by it. Am not closing the connection for time being.

Part of Main Code:

```
socket = serverSocket.accept();
/* Creating Thread for Multiple Client Architecture */
ClientHandler cliThread = new ClientHandler(socket);
cliThread.start();
```

In my thread class, I would like to have a hash-map variable that could store some key-value pair for me. But somehow it doesn't persist it. Main idea is to get each thread store its individual hash-map data, and it won't be shared among them anytime.

Code goes something like this:-

```
class ClientHandler extends Thread {
    private Socket socket;
    private Map<String,ClientData> tempClientDictionary ;
    //some listners

    public ClientHandler(Socket s) {
        socket = s;
        this.tempClientDictionary= new HashMap<String, ClientData>();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.err.println("Triggered RUN...");
        try {
             //some listners intialized
            while(true){
                //listening client here
                String str = (String) ois.readObject();
                System.out.println("CLIENT SAYS >"+str);
                //Based on some string and condition add few data in the hashmap 
                if(str.startsWith("START_ELECTION")){ //- FIRST IF CONDITION
                    //few lines of code
                    this.tempClientDictionary.put(client.getName(), client);

                    //At end checking **SIZE** , say 2
                    System.out.println("HashMap Size = "+this.tempClientDictionary.size()+" id="+ Thread.currentThread().getId());
                }else 
                //client requested something else here - SECOND IF CONDITION
                if(str.startsWith("OK")){
                    //**SIZE** IS 0 HERE
                    System.out.println("Hash Map Size = "+this.tempClientDictionary.size()+" id="+ Thread.currentThread().getId());

                }
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Any suggestion is appreciated. Thank you.

Client is an object - Data Access Object.

```
        String name;
        int Process_id;
        ObjectOutputStream writer;
        ObjectInputStream reader;

        public ClientData(String clientName, int processID){
            super();
            this.name = clientName;
            Process_id = processID;
        }
/* Followed by setter and getters */
```

Output:

```
Triggered RUN...

CLIENT SAYS >START_ELECTION#&#A5
----->START_ELECTION
START_ELECTION--HashMap Size = 0 Thread id=17

Triggered RUN...

CLIENT SAYS >START_ELECTION#&#B4
----->START_ELECTION
START_ELECTION--HashMap Size = 1 id=18

CLIENT SAYS >OK#&#A5#&#5
----->OK
 OK-- Hash Map Size = 0 id= 17

CLIENT SAYS >START_ELECTION#&#A5
----->START_ELECTION
START_ELECTION--HashMap Size = 0 id=17
```

Comment: what is `client` variable? I would say that `client.getName` returns the same string over and over again resulting in storage of only 1 entry in map.

Comment: @Antoniossss hi, I have added the client variable, its an data access object for storing the data in my hash-map as key value. Also am always getting size as  0, not even 1 in map.

Comment: Have you tried adding a breakpoint in the while loop and running it with the debugger?

Comment: @Jotunacorn I have kept print line for checking on while loop.(Updated Code)

It seems to executing only when client responds back to server. We take response string value and compare it with second if condition But it appears to be not having the same size as 2, but just 0.

Comment: There is no way this `HashMap` can escape the `Runnable` it is used in, in the code you have posted. Possibly you have a scoping problem somewhere else - for example, where is `client` declared? and how?

Comment: @EJP Hey, I have added the code link for reference. Actually my concern is 'tempClientDictionary' variable not client. It seems to be working well on that part.

Comment: Are you sure the START_ELECTION block is getting run?

Comment: @JohnHascall Yeah I have added the o/p as well for your consideration.

Comment: As I stated, there is no possible concern with the `tempClientDictionary` variable, unless it escapes in code you haven't posted, or you're clearing it ditto.

Comment: Can you include this.getId()'s value in those printlns?

Comment: @JohnHascall Thanks to you .. I have understood the problem, am expecting to get value from a thread where it is not stored. Actually each client has its own Reader and Writer maintained along with their own thread.

If you observe closely my o/p, I have HashMap Size = 1 on id=18(threadID)  , but in next line the client is responding on id-17, which has size as 0(A5-Client). Thank you for the guidance. Appreciate it!!